# Porque mesmo sem criar uma variável fazendo referência a os elementos no HTML o código continua funcionando?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
let demo = document.querySelector("#demo");
let button = document.querySelector("#button");

button.onclick = () => {
    demo.innerHTML = "Novo texto!";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<button id="button">click</button>
```

Acima o código é bem simples para ilustrar o que estou falando, eu criei duas variáveis `demo` e `button` fazendo referência aos elementos no *HTML*, quando for clicado no botão é alterado o texto dentro do parágrafo até aqui tudo bem, mas se eu remover as variáveis `demo` e `button` o código continua funcionando sem nenhum problema:

```js
button.onclick = () => {
    demo.innerHTML = "Novo texto!";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<button id="button">click</button>
```

Ou mais ainda, não é retornado nenhum erro como, por exemplo:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: button is not defined at
```

Não era para retornar um erro semelhante ao de cima já que a variável não foi definida ou não existe? porque isso acontece no código *JavaScript*?